# Insert to table based on another table if doesn’t exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

From doing a bit of research it seems it’s not possible to do an insert with a where clause?
I have a table I want to import into another table where specific record criteria doesn’t already exist. How would I go about this ?

E.g pseudo code -

```
insert into table b (select * from table a) where not exists tableb.column1 = tablea.column1 and tableb.column2 = tablea.column2
```

Could this potentially be done with a Join ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is, in fact, to **MERGE** two tables, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert using `INSERT INTO.. SELECT` with `NOT EXISTS`.

**Query**

```
insert into [TableB]
select * from [TableA] as [t1] -- [TableA] and [TableB] structure should be same.
where not exists(
    select 1 from [TableB] as [t2]
    where [t1].[column1] = [t2].[column1]
    and [t1].[column2] = [t2].[column2]
);
```

Or, if the table structure is not same and need to same few columns, then

**Query**

```
insert into [TableB]([column1], [column2], ..., [columnN])
select [column1], [column2], ..., [columnN] 
from [TableA] as [t1]
where not exists(
    select 1 from [TableB] as [t2]
    where [t1].[column1] = [t2].[column1]
    and [t1].[column2] = [t2].[column2]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` as below:

```
INSERT INTO tableb
SELECT a.* 
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON b.column1 = a.column1 
    AND b.column2 = a.column2
WHERE b.column1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing table name from INSERT statement in SELECT part will not work, because INSERT is not a query itself, but nothing prevents to query destination table in SELECT, which produces the data set to be inserted.

```
    INSERT INTO tableb (column1, column2)
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM tablea 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableb 
                      WHERE tableb.column1 = tablea.column1 
                      AND tabled.column2 = tablea.column2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Via Insert with **Select statement with Not Exists**

```
Declare @table1 table(Id int , EmpName varchar(100) )
Declare @table2 table(Id int , EmpName varchar(100) )

Insert into @table1 values (1,'Ajay'), (2, 'Tarak') , (3,'Nirav')

Insert into @table2 values (1,'Ajay')

--Insert into table b (select * from table a) where not exists tableb.column1 = tablea.column1 and tabled.column2 = tablea.column2 
INSERT INTO @table2 (id, empname)
   select id, empname from @table1
   EXCEPT
   SELECT id, empname from @table2


Select * from @table1
Select * from @table2
```

**Via merge**

```
Insert into @table2 values (4,'Prakash')
Select * from @table1
Select * from @table2


Declare @Id int , @EmpName varchar(100)
;with data as (select @id as id, @empname as empname from @table1)
   merge @table2 t
   using data s
      on s.id = t.id
     and s.empname = t.empname    
    when not matched by target
    then insert (id, empname) values (s.id, s.empname);


Select * from @table1
Select * from @table2
```